# WorkingMemoryEntryPoint.getFactHandle() efficiency

Tags: drools

In my application, I need to call very very very frecuently to
WorkingMemoryEntryPoint.getObject(), but I cannot keep the reference to the factHandle, so what I have to do is (in short):

getObject( getFactHandle( obj ) )

I´m not sure about how getFactHandle works internly, does it look up in the whole working memory until it gets the factHandle?? I guess it doesn´t, but if it does, I will have to keep a cache object-factHandle... (I hope drools does it for me, that´s what I´d like to know)...

Best regards,
César

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WorkingMemoryEntryPoint.getObject() internally ends up calling to: [SingleThreadedObjectStore.getObjectForHandle(handle)](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-core/src/main/java/org/drools/core/common/SingleThreadedObjectStore.java) which uses a Map to do the search:

Just for curiosity, why are you calling getFactHandle() for?

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks esteban. What I really want is to call "WorkingMemoryEntryPoint.getObject( Object obj )", but the only way to achieve it is by getObject( getFactHandle( obj ) ), am I wrong? I do guessed that getObject( FactHandle ) should use a Map, my question is that if getFactHandle( obj ) uses a Map also, or it looks up throughout the whole workin memory...

Comment: Just make sure that using a query in your drl files is not better than getting the fact handlers by hand. 
Regards,